# How to increase the bottom padding of the headline in my blog?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to increase the bottom padding of my headline in my blog and for some reason it is not being possible.

This is the code that I'm writing to increase the padding:

```
.post .type-post .entry-content h1.entry-title{
    padding: 0 0 50px;
}
```

Entry-title and Entry-content are the classes for H1 element.

Here is the link of the page where this issue exist -> https://www.writtenlyhub.com/writing-product-description/

I think this will help you in understand my problem better.

Please do help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be to use `padding-bottom: 50px;`

While there is nothing wrong in using shorthand, there is a recent video from Kevin Powell explaining some gotchas, I recommend you should [watch it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGkK-5il6Mk) and some other videos on his channel.

Answer (score 1):

`.post .type-post` would select an element with the class `type-post`, that is a *descendant* of an element with the class `post` - but you don't actually have that in your structure.

You have *one* element that has *both* classes - so the spacing between the two classes in your selector needs to be removed,

```
.post.type-post .entry-content h1.entry-title{
    padding: 0 0 50px;
}
```